# Safari browser is saving PDF files as numeric numbers and not the actual PDF name, Chrome can't handle this link

Tags: html, pdf, browser, safari, filenames

**Question 1**

I am trying to figure why Safari on a MacBook or Ipad 9 is saving our PDF files as a number instead of the actual PDF name. The link is a REST link that fetches the file from another server. The data is retrieved from a BLOB in the Database. I suspect it may have something to do with the file stream while it is downloading, so it could perhaps be the MimeType?

I have tested a normal PDF hosted on the website and it opens with the correct name and you can preview it.

I have searched a couple of sites, but can't find the answer.

[image]

You can find the website URL here: https://www.parrot.co.za/product/sku/twb-7519a and the PDF's are on the Documents tab.

Here is the HTML for the element. I have added the Download attribute a while ago, but it makes no difference.

```
<a href="https://accounts.parrotproducts.biz/PublicWebServices/ProductInfo.svc/ProductDocument/1/6733411" title="Click here to download this file." download="TWB-7519A - Specifications Sheet.pdf">TWB-7519A - Specifications Sheet.pdf</a>
```

[image]

**Question 2**

Another issue that I have is that Safari on an IPAD 9 can't open the PDF files, but Edge, Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Firefox work with no issues. The MacBook I am using, opens the files, but it has the same problem with the name being numeric numbers instead of the PDF name.

The IPAD is using software version 14.4.

I have also downloaded Chrome on the IPAD and attempted to open the downloaded PDF file, but then I get the following error:

"Chrome can't handle this link"
[image]

Comment: Because it is Apple where everything is stupid

Comment: @Nevermore, haha, true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer.

I have used a website to check the Response Headers and discovered that the closing quotation mark on the Filename section of the octet stream is not escaped properly. This is strange as all other browsers did not give any issues until we tested the links on an iPad or MacBook Air.

[image]